# Unable to access current frame being processed in the "ML Kit Vision Quickstart Sample App"

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-platform, computer-vision

I am working on an android project where I have access **facial landmarks** from the currently processed frame. Then I have to perform some calculation based on the face positions. At last I have to save the current frame being processed.

For this I am using [ML Kit Vision Quickstart Sample App](https://github.com/googlesamples/mlkit/tree/380fd036bfbcab2f7369148993a811dd73139480/android/vision-quickstart). This code is doing most of my work. From this code I am using the LivePreviewActivity.java, FaceDetectorProcessor.java and FaceGraphic.java class. I have performed all the calculations inside the FaceGraphics.java class. But I am NOT able to access the frame that is being processed currently.

```
LivePreviewActivity.java
/*
 * Copyright 2020 Google LLC. All rights reserved.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

package com.google.mlkit.vision.demo;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

import com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName;
import com.google.mlkit.common.model.LocalModel;
import com.google.mlkit.vision.demo.automl.AutoMLImageLabelerProcessor;
import com.google.mlkit.vision.demo.barcodescanner.BarcodeScannerProcessor;
import com.google.mlkit.vision.demo.facedetector.FaceDetectorProcessor;
import com.google.mlkit.vision.demo.labeldetector.LabelDetectorProcessor;
import com.google.mlkit.vision.demo.objectdetector.ObjectDetectorProcessor;
import com.google.mlkit.vision.demo.preference.PreferenceUtils;
import com.google.mlkit.vision.demo.preference.SettingsActivity;
import com.google.mlkit.vision.demo.preference.SettingsActivity.LaunchSource;
import com.google.mlkit.vision.demo.textdetector.TextRecognitionProcessor;
import com.google.mlkit.vision.face.FaceDetectorOptions;
import com.google.mlkit.vision.label.custom.CustomImageLabelerOptions;
import com.google.mlkit.vision.label.defaults.ImageLabelerOptions;
import com.google.mlkit.vision.objects.custom.CustomObjectDetectorOptions;
import com.google.mlkit.vision.objects.defaults.ObjectDetectorOptions;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Live preview demo for ML Kit APIs.
 */
@KeepName
public final class LivePreviewActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback,
        OnItemSelectedListener,
        CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener {
    private static final String FACE_DETECTION = "Face Detection";
    private static final String TAG = "LivePreviewActivity";
    private static final int PERMISSION_REQUESTS = 1;

    private CameraSource cameraSource = null;
    private CameraSourcePreview preview;
    private GraphicOverlay graphicOverlay;
    private String selectedModel = FACE_DETECTION;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_vision_live_preview);

        preview = findViewById(R.id.preview);

        if (preview == null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Preview is null");
        }
        graphicOverlay = findViewById(R.id.graphic_overlay);
        if (graphicOverlay == null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "graphicOverlay is null");
        }

        Spinner spinner = findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        List<String> options = new ArrayList<>();
        options.add(FACE_DETECTION);
        // Creating adapter for spinner
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.spinner_style, options);
        // Drop down layout style - list view with radio button
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        // attaching data adapter to spinner
        spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

        ToggleButton facingSwitch = findViewById(R.id.facing_switch);
        facingSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);

        ImageView settingsButton = findViewById(R.id.settings_button);
        settingsButton.setOnClickListener(
                v -> {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SettingsActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra(SettingsActivity.EXTRA_LAUNCH_SOURCE,
                            SettingsActivity.LaunchSource.LIVE_PREVIEW);
                    startActivity(intent);
                });

        if (allPermissionsGranted()) {
            createCameraSource(selectedModel);
        } else {
            getRuntimePermissions();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.live_preview_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.settings) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(SettingsActivity.EXTRA_LAUNCH_SOURCE, LaunchSource.LIVE_PREVIEW);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
        // An item was selected. You can retrieve the selected item using
        // parent.getItemAtPosition(pos)
        selectedModel = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
        Log.d(TAG, "Selected model: " + selectedModel);
        preview.stop();
        if (allPermissionsGranted()) {
            createCameraSource(selectedModel);
            startCameraSource();
        } else {
            getRuntimePermissions();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        // Do nothing.
    }

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Set facing");
        if (cameraSource != null) {
            if (isChecked) {
                cameraSource.setFacing(CameraSource.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT);
            } else {
                cameraSource.setFacing(CameraSource.CAMERA_FACING_BACK);
            }
        }
        preview.stop();
        startCameraSource();
    }

    private void createCameraSource(String model) {
        // If there's no existing cameraSource, create one.
        if (cameraSource == null) {
            cameraSource = new CameraSource(this, graphicOverlay);
        }

        try {
            Log.i(TAG, "Using Face Detector Processor");
            FaceDetectorOptions faceDetectorOptions = new FaceDetectorOptions.Builder()
                    .setContourMode(FaceDetectorOptions.CONTOUR_MODE_ALL)
                    .build();
                    // PreferenceUtils.getFaceDetectorOptionsForLivePreview(this);
            cameraSource.setMachineLearningFrameProcessor(
                    new FaceDetectorProcessor(this, faceDetectorOptions));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Can not create image processor: " + model, e);
            Toast.makeText(
                    getApplicationContext(),
                    "Can not create image processor: " + e.getMessage(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Starts or restarts the camera source, if it exists. If the camera source doesn't exist yet
     * (e.g., because onResume was called before the camera source was created), this will be called
     * again when the camera source is created.
     */
    private void startCameraSource() {
        if (cameraSource != null) {
            try {
                if (preview == null) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "resume: Preview is null");
                }
                if (graphicOverlay == null) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "resume: graphOverlay is null");
                }
                preview.start(cameraSource, graphicOverlay);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Unable to start camera source.", e);
                cameraSource.release();
                cameraSource = null;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.d(TAG, "onResume");
        createCameraSource(selectedModel);
        startCameraSource();
    }

    /**
     * Stops the camera.
     */
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        preview.stop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (cameraSource != null) {
            cameraSource.release();
        }
    }

    private String[] getRequiredPermissions() {
        try {
            PackageInfo info =
                    this.getPackageManager()
                            .getPackageInfo(this.getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS);
            String[] ps = info.requestedPermissions;
            if (ps != null && ps.length > 0) {
                return ps;
            } else {
                return new String[0];
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return new String[0];
        }
    }

    private boolean allPermissionsGranted() {
        for (String permission : getRequiredPermissions()) {
            if (!isPermissionGranted(this, permission)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    private void getRuntimePermissions() {
        List<String> allNeededPermissions = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String permission : getRequiredPermissions()) {
            if (!isPermissionGranted(this, permission)) {
                allNeededPermissions.add(permission);
            }
        }

        if (!allNeededPermissions.isEmpty()) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                    this, allNeededPermissions.toArray(new String[0]), PERMISSION_REQUESTS);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(
            int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Permission granted!");
        if (allPermissionsGranted()) {
            createCameraSource(selectedModel);
        }
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }

    private static boolean isPermissionGranted(Context context, String permission) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permission)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Permission granted: " + permission);
            return true;
        }
        Log.i(TAG, "Permission NOT granted: " + permission);
        return false;
    }
}
```

```
FaceDetectorProcessor.java
/*
 * Copyright 2020 Google LLC. All rights reserved.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

package com.google.mlkit.vision.demo.facedetector;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.PointF;
import android.util.Log;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.mlkit.vision.common.InputImage;
import com.google.mlkit.vision.demo.GraphicOverlay;
import com.google.mlkit.vision.demo.VisionProcessorBase;
import com.google.mlkit.vision.face.Face;
import com.google.mlkit.vision.face.FaceDetection;
import com.google.mlkit.vision.face.FaceDetector;
import com.google.mlkit.vision.face.FaceDetectorOptions;
import com.google.mlkit.vision.face.FaceLandmark;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

/**
 * Face Detector Demo.
 */
public class FaceDetectorProcessor extends VisionProcessorBase<List<Face>> {

    private static final String TAG = "FaceDetectorProcessor";

    private final FaceDetector detector;

    public FaceDetectorProcessor(Context context) {
        this(
                context,
                new FaceDetectorOptions.Builder()
                        .setClassificationMode(FaceDetectorOptions.CLASSIFICATION_MODE_ALL)
                        .enableTracking()
                        .build());
    }

    public FaceDetectorProcessor(Context context, FaceDetectorOptions options) {
        super(context);
        Log.v(MANUAL_TESTING_LOG, "Face detector options: " + options);
        detector = FaceDetection.getClient(options);
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
        super.stop();
        detector.close();
    }

    @Override
    protected Task<List<Face>> detectInImage(InputImage image) {
        return detector.process(image);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSuccess(@NonNull List<Face> faces, @NonNull GraphicOverlay graphicOverlay) {
        for (Face face : faces) {
            graphicOverlay.add(new FaceGraphic(graphicOverlay, face));
            logExtrasForTesting(face);
        }
    }

    private static void logExtrasForTesting(Face face) {
        if (face != null) {
            Log.v(MANUAL_TESTING_LOG, "face bounding box: " + face.getBoundingBox().flattenToString());
            Log.v(MANUAL_TESTING_LOG, "face Euler Angle X: " + face.getHeadEulerAngleX());
            Log.v(MANUAL_TESTING_LOG, "face Euler Angle Y: " + face.getHeadEulerAngleY());
            Log.v(MANUAL_TESTING_LOG, "face Euler Angle Z: " + face.getHeadEulerAngleZ());

            // All landmarks
            int[] landMarkTypes =
                    new int[]{
                            FaceLandmark.MOUTH_BOTTOM,
                            FaceLandmark.MOUTH_RIGHT,
                            FaceLandmark.MOUTH_LEFT,
                            FaceLandmark.RIGHT_EYE,
                            FaceLandmark.LEFT_EYE,
                            FaceLandmark.RIGHT_EAR,
                            FaceLandmark.LEFT_EAR,
                            FaceLandmark.RIGHT_CHEEK,
                            FaceLandmark.LEFT_CHEEK,
                            FaceLandmark.NOSE_BASE
                    };
            String[] landMarkTypesStrings =
                    new String[]{
                            "MOUTH_BOTTOM",
                            "MOUTH_RIGHT",
                            "MOUTH_LEFT",
                            "RIGHT_EYE",
                            "LEFT_EYE",
                            "RIGHT_EAR",
                            "LEFT_EAR",
                            "RIGHT_CHEEK",
                            "LEFT_CHEEK",
                            "NOSE_BASE"
                    };
            for (int i = 0; i < landMarkTypes.length; i++) {
                FaceLandmark landmark = face.getLandmark(landMarkTypes[i]);
                if (landmark == null) {
                    Log.v(
                            MANUAL_TESTING_LOG,
                            "No landmark of type: " + landMarkTypesStrings[i] + " has been detected");
                } else {
                    PointF landmarkPosition = landmark.getPosition();
                    String landmarkPositionStr =
                            String.format(Locale.US, "x: %f , y: %f", landmarkPosition.x, landmarkPosition.y);
                    Log.v(
                            MANUAL_TESTING_LOG,
                            "Position for face landmark: "
                                    + landMarkTypesStrings[i]
                                    + " is :"
                                    + landmarkPositionStr);
                }
            }
            Log.v(
                    MANUAL_TESTING_LOG,
                    "face left eye open probability: " + face.getLeftEyeOpenProbability());
            Log.v(
                    MANUAL_TESTING_LOG,
                    "face right eye open probability: " + face.getRightEyeOpenProbability());
            Log.v(MANUAL_TESTING_LOG, "face smiling probability: " + face.getSmilingProbability());
            Log.v(MANUAL_TESTING_LOG, "face tracking id: " + face.getTrackingId());
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Face detection failed " + e);
    }
}
```

```
FaceGraphics.java
/*
 * Copyright 2020 Google LLC. All rights reserved.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

package com.google.mlkit.vision.demo.facedetector;

import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.PointF;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.mlkit.vision.demo.GraphicOverlay;
import com.google.mlkit.vision.demo.GraphicOverlay.Graphic;
import com.google.mlkit.vision.face.Face;
import com.google.mlkit.vision.face.FaceContour;
import com.google.mlkit.vision.face.FaceLandmark;
import com.google.mlkit.vision.face.FaceLandmark.LandmarkType;

import java.util.Locale;

/**
 * Graphic instance for rendering face position, contour, and landmarks within the associated
 * graphic overlay view.
 */
public class FaceGraphic extends Graphic {
    private static final float FACE_POSITION_RADIUS = 4.0f;
    private static final float ID_TEXT_SIZE = 30.0f;
    private static final float ID_Y_OFFSET = 40.0f;
    private static final float ID_X_OFFSET = -40.0f;
    private static final float BOX_STROKE_WIDTH = 5.0f;
    private static final int NUM_COLORS = 10;
    private static final int[][] COLORS = new int[][]{
            // {Text color, background color}
            {Color.BLACK, Color.WHITE},
            {Color.WHITE, Color.MAGENTA},
            {Color.BLACK, Color.LTGRAY},
            {Color.WHITE, Color.RED},
            {Color.WHITE, Color.BLUE},
            {Color.WHITE, Color.DKGRAY},
            {Color.BLACK, Color.CYAN},
            {Color.BLACK, Color.YELLOW},
            {Color.WHITE, Color.BLACK},
            {Color.BLACK, Color.GREEN}
    };

    private final Paint facePositionPaint;
    private final Paint[] idPaints;
    private final Paint[] boxPaints;
    private final Paint[] labelPaints;

    private volatile Face face;

    FaceGraphic(GraphicOverlay overlay, Face face) {
        super(overlay);

        this.face = face;
        final int selectedColor = Color.WHITE;

        facePositionPaint = new Paint();
        facePositionPaint.setColor(selectedColor);

        int numColors = COLORS.length;
        idPaints = new Paint[numColors];
        boxPaints = new Paint[numColors];
        labelPaints = new Paint[numColors];
        for (int i = 0; i < numColors; i++) {
            idPaints[i] = new Paint();
            idPaints[i].setColor(COLORS[i][0] /* text color */);
            idPaints[i].setTextSize(ID_TEXT_SIZE);

            boxPaints[i] = new Paint();
            boxPaints[i].setColor(COLORS[i][1] /* background color */);
            boxPaints[i].setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            boxPaints[i].setStrokeWidth(BOX_STROKE_WIDTH);

            labelPaints[i] = new Paint();
            labelPaints[i].setColor(COLORS[i][1]  /* background color */);
            labelPaints[i].setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Draws the face annotations for position on the supplied canvas.
     */
    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        Face face = this.face;

        if (face == null) {
            return;
        }

        // Draws a circle at the position of the detected face, with the face's track id below.
        float x0 = translateX(face.getBoundingBox().centerX());
        float y0 = translateY(face.getBoundingBox().centerY());
        // canvas.drawCircle(x0, y0, FACE_POSITION_RADIUS, facePositionPaint);

        // Calculate positions.
        float left = x0 - scale(face.getBoundingBox().width() / 2.0f);
        float top = y0 - scale(face.getBoundingBox().height() / 2.0f);
        float right = x0 + scale(face.getBoundingBox().width() / 2.0f);
        float bottom = y0 + scale(face.getBoundingBox().height() / 2.0f);
        float lineHeight = ID_TEXT_SIZE + BOX_STROKE_WIDTH;
        float yLabelOffset = -lineHeight;

        // Decide color based on face ID
        int colorID = (face.getTrackingId() == null)
                ? 0 : Math.abs(face.getTrackingId() % NUM_COLORS);

        /**
        // Calculate width and height of label box
        float textWidth = idPaints[colorID].measureText("ID: " + face.getTrackingId());
        if (face.getSmilingProbability() != null) {
            yLabelOffset -= lineHeight;
            textWidth = Math.max(textWidth, idPaints[colorID].measureText(
                    String.format(Locale.US, "Happiness: %.2f", face.getSmilingProbability())));
        }
        if (face.getLeftEyeOpenProbability() != null) {
            yLabelOffset -= lineHeight;
            textWidth = Math.max(textWidth, idPaints[colorID].measureText(
                    String.format(Locale.US, "Left eye: %.2f", face.getLeftEyeOpenProbability())));
        }
        if (face.getRightEyeOpenProbability() != null) {
            yLabelOffset -= lineHeight;
            textWidth = Math.max(textWidth, idPaints[colorID].measureText(
                    String.format(Locale.US, "Right eye: %.2f", face.getLeftEyeOpenProbability())));
        }

        // Draw labels
        canvas.drawRect(left - BOX_STROKE_WIDTH,
                top + yLabelOffset,
                left + textWidth + (2 * BOX_STROKE_WIDTH),
                top,
                labelPaints[colorID]);
        yLabelOffset += ID_TEXT_SIZE;
        canvas.drawRect(left, top, right, bottom, boxPaints[colorID]);
        canvas.drawText("ID: " + face.getTrackingId(), left, top + yLabelOffset,
                idPaints[colorID]);
        yLabelOffset += lineHeight;
        **/

        /**
        // Draws all face contours.
        for (FaceContour contour : face.getAllContours()) {
            for (PointF point : contour.getPoints()) {
                canvas.drawCircle(
                        translateX(point.x), translateY(point.y), FACE_POSITION_RADIUS, facePositionPaint);
            }
        }
        **/

        FaceContour contour = face.getContour(FaceContour.NOSE_BRIDGE);
        float x1 = 0, y1 = 0;
        for (PointF point : contour.getPoints()) {
            // canvas.drawCircle(translateX(point.x), translateY(point.y), FACE_POSITION_RADIUS, facePositionPaint);
            x1 = translateX(point.x);
            y1 = translateY(point.y);
            break;
        }

        /**
        // Draws smiling and left/right eye open probabilities.
        if (face.getSmilingProbability() != null) {
            canvas.drawText(
                    "Smiling: " + String.format(Locale.US, "%.2f", face.getSmilingProbability()),
                    left,
                    top + yLabelOffset,
                    idPaints[colorID]);
            yLabelOffset += lineHeight;
        }
        **/

        /**
        FaceLandmark leftEye = face.getLandmark(FaceLandmark.LEFT_EYE);
        if (leftEye != null && face.getLeftEyeOpenProbability() != null) {
            canvas.drawText(
                    "Left eye open: " + String.format(Locale.US, "%.2f", face.getLeftEyeOpenProbability()),
                    translateX(leftEye.getPosition().x) + ID_X_OFFSET,
                    translateY(leftEye.getPosition().y) + ID_Y_OFFSET,
                    idPaints[colorID]);
        } else if (leftEye != null && face.getLeftEyeOpenProbability() == null) {
            canvas.drawText(
                    "Left eye",
                    left,
                    top + yLabelOffset,
                    idPaints[colorID]);
            yLabelOffset += lineHeight;
        } else if (leftEye == null && face.getLeftEyeOpenProbability() != null) {
            canvas.drawText(
                    "Left eye open: " + String.format(Locale.US, "%.2f", face.getLeftEyeOpenProbability()),
                    left,
                    top + yLabelOffset,
                    idPaints[colorID]);
            yLabelOffset += lineHeight;
        }

        FaceLandmark rightEye = face.getLandmark(FaceLandmark.RIGHT_EYE);
        if (rightEye != null && face.getRightEyeOpenProbability() != null) {
            canvas.drawText(
                    "Right eye open: " + String.format(Locale.US, "%.2f", face.getRightEyeOpenProbability()),
                    translateX(rightEye.getPosition().x) + ID_X_OFFSET,
                    translateY(rightEye.getPosition().y) + ID_Y_OFFSET,
                    idPaints[colorID]);
        } else if (rightEye != null && face.getRightEyeOpenProbability() == null) {
            canvas.drawText(
                    "Right eye",
                    left,
                    top + yLabelOffset,
                    idPaints[colorID]);
            yLabelOffset += lineHeight;
        } else if (rightEye == null && face.getRightEyeOpenProbability() != null) {
            canvas.drawText(
                    "Right eye open: " + String.format(Locale.US, "%.2f", face.getRightEyeOpenProbability()),
                    left,
                    top + yLabelOffset,
                    idPaints[colorID]);
        }
        **/

        /**
        // Draw facial landmarks
        drawFaceLandmark(canvas, FaceLandmark.LEFT_EYE);
        drawFaceLandmark(canvas, FaceLandmark.RIGHT_EYE);
        drawFaceLandmark(canvas, FaceLandmark.LEFT_CHEEK);
        drawFaceLandmark(canvas, FaceLandmark.RIGHT_CHEEK);
        **/
    }

    private void drawFaceLandmark(Canvas canvas, @LandmarkType int landmarkType) {
        FaceLandmark faceLandmark = face.getLandmark(landmarkType);
        if (faceLandmark != null) {
            canvas.drawCircle(
                    translateX(faceLandmark.getPosition().x),
                    translateY(faceLandmark.getPosition().y),
                    FACE_POSITION_RADIUS,
                    facePositionPaint);
        }
    }
}
```

In the above code I want to access the current frame being processed. Either inside the LivePreviewActivity or FaceGraphics.java.

Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

By Frame , i am assuming you want the bitmap which satisfy your algorithm . Also as you mentioned that you are using ***LivePreviewActivity*** that means you are real time face detection.

There is no way to access the bitmap or current frame from ***FaceDetectorProcessor***

Instead what you need to do is to access the original Image inside **VisionProcessorBase.java**

modify the common process logic like this to pass the current bitmap to FaceDetectorProcessor

```
// -----------------Common processing logic-------------------------------------------------------
    private Task<T> requestDetectInImage(
            final InputImage image,
            final GraphicOverlay graphicOverlay,
            @Nullable final Bitmap originalCameraImage,
            boolean shouldShowFps) {
        final long startMs = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
        return detectInImage(image)
                .addOnSuccessListener(
                        executor,
                        results -> {
                            long currentLatencyMs = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - startMs;
                            numRuns++;
                            frameProcessedInOneSecondInterval++;
                            totalRunMs += currentLatencyMs;
                            maxRunMs = Math.max(currentLatencyMs, maxRunMs);
                            minRunMs = Math.min(currentLatencyMs, minRunMs);

                            // Only log inference info once per second. When frameProcessedInOneSecondInterval is
                            // equal to 1, it means this is the first frame processed during the current second.
                            if (frameProcessedInOneSecondInterval == 1) {
                                Log.d(TAG, "Max latency is: " + maxRunMs);
                                Log.d(TAG, "Min latency is: " + minRunMs);
                                Log.d(TAG, "Num of Runs: " + numRuns + ", Avg latency is: " + totalRunMs / numRuns);
                                MemoryInfo mi = new MemoryInfo();
                                activityManager.getMemoryInfo(mi);
                                long availableMegs = mi.availMem / 0x100000L;
                                Log.d(TAG, "Memory available in system: " + availableMegs + " MB");
                            }

                            graphicOverlay.clear();
                            if (originalCameraImage != null) {
                                graphicOverlay.add(new CameraImageGraphic(graphicOverlay, originalCameraImage));
                            }
 //passing the original bitmap to FaceDetectorProcessor                          

VisionProcessorBase.this.onSuccess(originalCameraImage,results, graphicOverlay);
                                graphicOverlay.add(
                                        new InferenceInfoGraphic(
                                                graphicOverlay, currentLatencyMs, shouldShowFps ? framesPerSecond : null));
                                graphicOverlay.postInvalidate();
                            })
                    .addOnFailureListener(
                            executor,
                            e -> {
                                graphicOverlay.clear();
                                graphicOverlay.postInvalidate();
                                String error = "Failed to process. Error: " + e.getLocalizedMessage();
                                Toast.makeText(
                                        graphicOverlay.getContext(),
                                        error + "\nCause: " + e.getCause(),
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                        .show();
                                Log.d(TAG, error);
                                e.printStackTrace();
                                VisionProcessorBase.this.onFailure(e);
                            });
        }
```

You also need to change abstract onSuccess FaceDetectorProcessor  like this :

```
protected abstract void onSuccess(Bitmap currentBitmap,@NonNull T results, @NonNull GraphicOverlay graphicOverlay);
```

After the required changes , you can access the **currentBitmap** in onSuccess Method inside **FaceDetectorProcessor**  and you can also pass this to **FaceGraphic.java** from here

```
   @Override
    protected void onSuccess(Bitmap currentBitmap, @NonNull List<Face> faces, @NonNull GraphicOverlay graphicOverlay) {
        for (Face face : faces) {

            graphicOverlay.add(new FaceGraphic(currentBitmap,graphicOverlay, face));
            logExtrasForTesting(face);
        }
    }
```

Inside **FaceGraphic.java** access current bitmap from constructor

```
FaceGraphic(Bitmap currentBitmap,GraphicOverlay overlay, Face face) {

this.currentBitmap = currentBitmap;
}
```

I hope this will help you out and fulfill your need.

Comment: how to get processed bitmap in LivePreviewActivity.class?