# How to get ML Kit face detection Processed Frame in Android

Tags: android, android-bitmap, google-mlkit

I am working on an android project where I have to detect person face At last I have to save the current frame being processed.

For this I am using ML Kit Vision Quickstart Sample App. This code is doing most of my work. From this code I am using the LivePreviewActivity.java.

Now i want to get detected face frame and convert it to bitmap to save as Image.

[ML Kit face detection](https://github.com/googlesamples/mlkit/tree/master/android/vision-quickstart)

Comment: Hi, did you find any solution?

Comment: yes ... will post my  and here

Comment: Great,that would be nice!Update your solution,will upvote it!

Comment: Hi @unkn , Can you share solution here, facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Face detector would return a bounding box for the detected faces. So if you keep the original image, and then you could crop the image with the bounding box.

You could keep the [original image](https://github.com/googlesamples/mlkit/blob/master/android/vision-quickstart/app/src/main/java/com/google/mlkit/vision/demo/java/VisionProcessorBase.java#L117) before you calling into process() method. To convert the image to bitmap, you could check [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/mlkit/blob/master/android/vision-quickstart/app/src/main/java/com/google/mlkit/vision/demo/BitmapUtils.java#L49).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63270873/unable-to-access-current-frame-being-processed-in-the-ml-kit-vision-quickstart